# Catch exception thrown from Delphi DLL in C#

Tags: c#, delphi, dll, pinvoke, dllimport

A problem I recently encountered is following.

I've a .DLL written in Delphi this DLL has a function Divide (which accepts two integers as parameter)
and returns its value as it should.

```
function Divide( aFirstValue, aSecondValue : Integer ) : Double; stdcall;
begin
  result := aFirstValue / aSecondValue;
end;
```

Now if I use the following parameters '5, 0' then it throws a DivideByZeroException (which is correct :))

But when I call the same .DLL from C# it doesn't catch any exception at all.

```
[DllImport("DelphiDLL.DLL", EntryPoint = "Divide", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true,
CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern float Divide(Int32 a, Int32 b);

private void Button_Click_2(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
       TB.Text += "Divide(a,b) = ";
       float temp;
       temp = Divide(Convert.ToInt32(aTB.Text), Convert.ToInt32(bTB.Text));

       Console.WriteLine(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

       TB.Text += Convert.ToString(temp) + "\r\n";
    }
    catch (DivideByZeroException eMsg)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: is anything returned?

Comment: Yeah in C# it shows Infinite so a value is returned but it could also be 0.0....nth

Comment: How about don't calling divide method when *divisor* is zero ? Anyway you know input isn't valid right?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - that would deal with *this* problem, but doesn't solve the problem of why exceptions aren't being returned to the calling c# method.

Comment: @user1666620 I haven't said it will solve the problem. If you know something is wrong right away, why do you still do it?

Comment: Then why would one use the DivideByZeroException if you know it upfront. Because you might want to check it after a hefty calculation. The 5/0 was just an example

Comment: Then why would you have validations at all? From your question it seems that `0` is from user input, So validation is mandatory. If that `0` comes as the result of some calculation, I agree with you..

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - i'm not sure it's a good idea to have a module in a project which might be used in several places, but only if you've already checked for possible special circumstances x, y and z. by rights, it's the module which is being used which should check the inputs and return the error.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Don't knock OP for using a simplistic example to demonstrate his problem. His problem is clearly stated. And at least he made an effort to provide simple clear code examples. This is much better than a large number of questions that expect help without putting in any effort to distill the problem. (I've edited the title to remove reference to the specific exception, as that's clearly not important based on the body of the question.)

Comment: @CraigYoung I'm not nitpicking, my point is when dealing with divisions just validate the inputs. You can take my comment into consideration if you feel I'm right. Simply it can be taken as a side note. And you say it is simplistic example, why do UI elements comes in simplistic example? I think that's how OP gets the data from. So clearly a candidate for validations..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot hope to catch that exception outside the DLL. One of the rules of this form of binary interop is that exceptions cannot be thrown across module boundaries.

The solution is to fix the DLL. Catch the exception in the DLL and return an error code to indicate failure. Indeed you should protect all entry points against throwing an exception. Don't just catch zero divide exceptions, catch them all and convert them into error code return values.

```
function CalcQuotient(a, b: Integer; out quotient: Double): Integer; stdcall;
begin
  try
    quotient := a / b;
    Result := 0;// you'd use a constant with a sensible name rather than a magic value
  except
    on E: Exception do begin
      Result := GetErrorCode(E);
      // where GetErrorCode is your function that converts exceptions into error codes
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Some asides regarding your p/invoke usage:

1. There's no need to specify `CharSet` when none of the arguments contains text.
2. `SetLastError = true` is incorrect and should be removed. The function doesn't call `SetLastError`. Consequently the call to `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` is erroneous and should be removed.

Comment: David as you've stated 'You cannot hope' does this imply that it just isn't possible or there is still a spark of hope?? Just wondering.

I'll have a look in the error codes.

Comment: @Blaatz0r Maybe there's some sneaky way to catch them, but I doubt it. Anyway, you aren't meant to throw them, so don't!

Comment: @Blaatz0r The exception raised in Delphi would be `EZeroDivide`. This is an object that is specific to the Delphi world. C# won't be able to use it correctly. Yes, some standard exception types _could_ be mapped from Delphi to C# such as `EZeroDivide` --> `DivideByZeroException`, but that would still leave custom exception types unaccounted for. They could only be mapped via some lowest common denominator. Some interop frameworks may be able marshall exceptions between Delphi and C#. But under the skin they'll be doing the same sort of thing demonstrated in David's answer.

Comment: @CraigYoung your right on the Delphi exception (EZeroDivide) when typing the C# variant came to mind so thats why I've written DivideByZeroException :)